# Corona sdk best way to go about build.settings and config.lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to make a math game but I have come into several problems.  The first is that In the android emulator that comes with corona I have black space at the top and bottom.  These are my files:

config.lua:

```
local aspectRatio = display.pixelHeight / display.pixelWidth
application = {
   content = {
      width = 320
      height = 480
      scale = "letterBox",
      fps = 30,

   },
}
```

build.settings:

```
local aspectRatio = display.pixelHeight / display.pixelWidth
application = {
   content = {
      width = 320
      height = 480
      scale = "letterBox",
      fps = 30,

   },
}
```

It shows my image correctly but I get black at the top and bottom.  I read tutorials about these to files, but they are so complex.  What is the easiest way to may these files work?  The tutorials I read also tried to find each device that this app could be running on and makes the settings accordingly, but id like to be more cross-platform and not have to update the app every time their is a new size of device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to the black bars at the top and bottom, that is a side-effect of "letterbox" scaling.

Corona automatically scales your content so that it fills as much of the screen space as possible, WHILE maintaining aspect ratio of your original content. This means that it will scale the content up until it hits either the top/bottom edge or the left/right edge of the screen.

When it hits an edge, it stops scaling the content. That may result in the black bars you're seeing right now.

This tutorial [here](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/12/04/the-ultimate-config-lua-file/) is the most comprehensive tutorial available.

That tutorial has a file (the ultimate config.lua file) that you can download and use in your app's build. Also [found here](http://www.dropbox.com/s/yzs8bfc0drs4rwo/config.lua)!

Comment: When I used the file it just makes a single blackspace

Comment: Correct. This file is just one of them you need. You're project folder should contain at least a config.lua, build.settings, and main.lua file.

Any display objects, game/app logic, or images should be created and maintained from within the "main.lua" file only.

Comment: No I mean it displays my image with my main file but it has one black part at the bottom